# Can I change statusCode to code on Boom error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, hapi

I'm doing an API and on the Boom error payload the responses I'm getting, for example, is:

```java
{
    "statusCode": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Method Not Allowed"
}
```

But on another API that I'm using, the `statusCode` field should be renamed just to `code`, so the response would look like this:

```
{
    "code": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Method Not Allowed"
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to do this on `Boom` or if there is another way to do it.

Comment: @ııı  `Boom` is a `Hapi`'s library to handle errors on an easier way, as they say on their on doc, "HTTP-friendly error objects" https://github.com/hapijs/boom

Answer (score 0):

I did not found a way to rename `statusCode` to `code` within the boom library.

One way to achieve what you want is to write a small server extension to grab the boom object and return a custom error payload. Downside, you will loose the Boom Object itself.

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, h) => {
    const response = request.response;
    if (!response.isBoom) {
      return h.continue;
    }

    const renameProp = (cProp, nProp, { [cProp]: cValue, ...rest }) => ({
      [nProp]: cValue,
      ...rest,
    });

    return h
      .response(renameProp('statusCode', 'code', response.output.payload))
      .code(response.output.statusCode);
  });
```

[Hapi Docs - How to implement a server extension](https://hapijs.com/api#server.ext.args())

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did something almost like that, I created an error handler that changes de error prototype object, replacing the `code` property to an `statusCode` property defined by me

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to create an error handler that replaces the `statusCode` property on the `Error` prototype . Now it looks like this:

```
async function errorHandler (
    request: Hapi.Request,
    h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit) {
        if (request.response instanceof Error) {
            Object.defineProperty(request.response.output.payload, 'code',
            Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(request.response.output.payload, 'statusCode'));

            delete request.response.output.payload.statusCode;
        }
        return h.continue;
}
```